# Illegal char <:> at index 44: \edu\stanford\nlp\models\kbp\tokensregex\per:siblings.rules

Tags: android, android-studio, stanford-nlp

I got this error in android studio while trying to run the CoreNLP, I imported the jars (maybe not?)

thi is the screenshot:
[image]